# New ssd, keep win 10 licensed?

Tags: windows-10, license

upgraded from win 7 to win 10 a few months ago.
Just bought a new ssd.
How do I maintain my license for windows 10?
Install normally and use the serial number I currently have?

Comment: You should have no issues with installing on new ssd hard drive.

Comment: Just install Windows 10 on the SSD it will automatically activate itself.  You don't even have to provide it a key when you install it.

Comment: Sounds wierd, by what it will activate itself?

Comment: @OrelVadana Your hardware fingerprint. Using a fuzzy matching algorithm, it tries to find your PC in the activation database.

Answer (score 7):

> **New ssd, keep win 10 licensed?**
>
> Just bought a new ssd. How do I maintain my license for windows 10?

---

> [**How the Free Windows 10 License
>   Works**](http://www.howtogeek.com/226510/how-to-use-your-free-windows-10-license-after-changing-your-pc%E2%80%99s-hardware/)
>
> The free Windows 10 license Microsoft is providing to upgraders works
>   differently. Microsoft won’t issue you a Windows 10 product key.
>   Instead, when you perform an upgrade from within Windows 7 Service
>   Pack 1 or Windows 8.1, the upgrade process registers a unique ID
>   associated with your PC’s hardware on Microsoft’s Windows activation
>   servers.
>
> In the future, whenever you install Windows 10 on that same PC, it
>   will automatically report to Microsoft’s activation servers. Microsoft
>   will confirm that the PC with that specific hardware configuration is
>   allowed to use Windows 10, and it’ll automatically be activated.
>
> This isn’t actually made clear in the installation process itself. To
>   clean-install Windows 10 on a machine activated in this way, you have
>   to continually skip all the product key prompts while installing it.
>
> This automatic process only works if your PC has the same hardware it
>   had when you upgraded to Windows 10.

*I'm not certain if an SDD would count as the hardware change that'd affect the free hardware-tied Windows 10 activation, but if so. . .*

> [**What if You Change Your PC’s Hardware?**](http://www.howtogeek.com/226510/how-to-use-your-free-windows-10-license-after-changing-your-pc%E2%80%99s-hardware/)
>
> Microsoft has never actually wanted to explain exactly how the
>   hardware-based Windows activation process works. Just replacing your
>   hard drive or upgrading your graphics card shouldn’t cause a problem.
>   If you’ve just changed a few peripherals, Windows 10 may just
>   automatically activate itself after you clean-install it.
>
> However, replacing your computer’s motherboard or CPU will likely be
>   so big a change that it prevents the PC from automatically activating.
>   Windows 10 will see it as a different hardware configuration, one
>   which isn’t allowed to have the free upgrade.
>
> If you run into this problem, you should just be able to clean-install
>   Windows 10 normally. Skip both prompts when you’re asked to enter a
>   product key. After it installs, it will attempt to activate itself
>   with Microsoft and won’t automatically activate. It will be considered
>   non-genuine until you activate it. The activation screen will prompt
>   you to purchase a new license from the Windows Store.
>
> According to Gabriel Aul, Vice President of Engineering for the
>   Windows & Devices group at Microsoft, you can then contact support
>   from within Windows 10, explain the situation, and they’ll activate
>   Windows 10 for you:
>
> To do this, you should be able to open the Start menu, select All
>   Apps, and launch the Contact Support app included with Windows 10.
>   Navigate to the Services & apps > Windows > Setting up category, which
>   includes activation issues. You can text-chat with a Microsoft support
>   representative here or have a Microsoft representative call you on the
>   phone.
>
> The free Windows 10 license isn’t tied to a Microsoft account at all —
>   it’s just tied to the PC’s hardware configuration. However, we assume
>   that it might help if you sign into the PC with the same Microsoft
>   account you signed in with on your old PC. That would give Microsoft
>   Support some way to confirm you previously had a free Windows 10
>   license on that PC. That’s just a guess, of course — Microsoft isn’t
>   saying exactly what is required here.

Comment: TL;DR: Skip entering product key during Setup, the end. :D

Comment: @OrelVadana When you get a chance, please let me know whether or not my answer was helpful. I'd like to close the loop on the inquirty if so.