# What happens to my Windows 10 license when I install fresh on a new SSD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, license

I have Windows 10 Home with a license running off of an HDD in my laptop.

I would like to replace the HDD with an SSD and then install a fresh copy of Windows 10 Home on the SSD.

What will happen to my license? Will the Microsoft license servers recognize that my copy is licensed or is there any action I need to take to move the license from the old HDD over to the new SSD?

Comment: Relevant: [Is it possible to transfer an OEM Windows 10 license?](https://superuser.com/questions/1082510/is-it-possible-to-transfer-an-oem-windows-10-license?rq=1) and [Does Windows 10 OEM License will work if I replace the HDD and install the windows from Microsoft ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1228393/does-windows-10-oem-license-will-work-if-i-replace-the-hdd-and-install-the-windo?rq=1) and [Clean install of Windows 10 OEM: license key issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/1033160/clean-install-of-windows-10-oem-license-key-issues?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Having done exactly this myself I found the eaiest way to migrate the licence safely, was to first assoicate your account with a microsoft account (i.e. hotmail, outlook.com, xbox, etc).

How to do this is explained here: [Microsoft Insider Blog on Microsoft Accounts in windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_security/how-to-connect-to-a-microsoft-account-in-windows/c1614fe6-a9cd-4723-a9e0-7293d9cdfd4a)

Basically:

1. Start Menu
2. Settings
3. Accounts
4. Select your account
5. Select 'Connect to Microsoft Account' and sign in with your account details.

Once you've done this, it links the licence key of the windows you're using, to your account.

Next proceed with your install of your new ssd, install windows as normal and when it asks you for the 'CD Key' - just choose the box which states something like 'I dont have the key right now'.

Once you've finished the setup, gone through the tutorials etc, you can repeat the above steps, sign into your microsoft account again, and then it'll check and use the licence.

If you want to double check it's got the key, just to go the settings -> system and look for the activation message.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the following articles: 
- http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/275586-32-upgrading-transfer-windows-license 
- [New ssd, keep win 10 licensed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1032890/new-ssd-keep-win-10-licensed)

Basicly Windows checks if hardware changes were detected on the device. If it's a small device like a mouse, storage, ... then it won't complain. Changing your CPU or Motherboard can cause a problem. You should be fine with just transfering the data to your SDD. Hopefully you can give us the answer when you're tried it, there's no real damage in just copying from HDD->SDD and trying it to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't think just copying OS files from HDD to SSD will work as there also needs to be done some work setting up the boot loader etc.

Comment: @urig You are correct but when I moved my installation from HDD to SSD I downloaded the manufacturer software and was able to clone everything, including the boot sectors which made the transfer simple.